# Panel Data with 2 IV and 1 DV

Tags: hypothesis-testing, least-squares, panel-data, spss, controlling-for-a-variable

I am working on my thesis and I have a few questions about which method I should use for the analysis of my data.
My research is about inequality in Europe, and in general households in Europe that have access to broadband internet connections and what its effects are on their educational attainment.
The IV here would be

1. % of households that have access to a broadband connection
2. GINI Index of the country (to mesure inequality between the countries)

The dependent variable would be a variable that can be divided in 3 groups:
. % of population that completed primary education, % of population that completed secundary education, and finally % of population that completed tertiary education.

The data is available on the World Bank database and has about 20 countries over a period of 15 years. After doing some research I figured out that the type of data i'm using is Panel Data. I have done some reading about it, but I can't figure out how to continue, because most of the tutorials only use one IV and on DV.
What I have read suggests using OLS(my promotor also told me that OLS would be best suited) for the type of variables and data I'm using and that I will need control variables like "population" or "unemployment", but I don't get it.

I don't know if I'm being clear here, I basically want to know if I need to do what I read (but then I have no clue on how to work with 2IV and 1 DV), or if it's something completely different..?

If something isn't clear, let me know, and I'll try to explain better. Thank you very much.

edit:  I checked a bit more, and I think I might have to rethink my DV, because it seems as what I want to achieve is multiple DV's and that would make things more complex than they need to be. My aim, and my research question actually is about the digital divide and what effects access to broadband internet has on the educational attainment. Maybe I should go for a single DV (that is continuous), like "% of people that completed college" instead. Would OLS Linear regression still be a good method? Thank you.